# Is there a way to create this report by Looping over the list of dates?

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

This is for a .net core 3.1 application, using Blazor for front end.

I have a list of dates that I need to take, and then build an "analysis" report using those dates. The analysis basically needs to look at the dates and tell me how many dates fall on each day of the week, and also how many dates are in each month of the year. This fis for an Human Resources application where they are tracking employee absences.

I have a List that I've built, and I'm passing it into a method that then performs an analysis.

```
public class DateHourResponseModel
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public int Hours { get; set; }
    }
```

I figured I could then take that list, and create a list of "Responses", each for a different day of the week, and month of the year. I figured for "Type" I could just use the DateTime.DayOfWeek, DateTime.Month and get an into (0-6 for day of week, 1-12 for month) which is why I have the "IsMonth" bool on there.

```
public class AbsenceAnalysisResponse
{
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public bool IsMonth { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public int Hours { get; set; }
}
```

And This class, which is just a list of the above:

```
public class AbsenceAnalysis
{
     public List<AbsenceAnalysisResponse> Responses { get; set; }

}
```

My question is: Is there a way to build this analysis report by doing a foreach on the list of dates that I start with? I haven't figured out a way to create this list without doing something like this:

```
var analysisResponses = new List<AbsenceAnalysisResponse>
        {
            new AbsenceAnalysisResponse
            {
                Type = 0,
                IsMonth = false,
                Count = dateHourModel.Count(x => (int)x.Date.DayOfWeek == 0),
                Hours = dateHourModel.Where(x => (int)x.Date.DayOfWeek == 0).Sum(x => x.Hours)
            },
```

I feel like an idiot because I know there has got to be a more elegant way of doing this, and maybe the problem is how I'm approaching it. I have the analysis working and displaying on the front end but I absolutely hate how I'm creating the list of "responses". I'm still pretty green behind the ears with this, and I don't know if I just haven't been searching the right questions online or what, but I haven't found anything where someone is doing something similar. Thanks for any help, and please let me know if there is any information I need to provide.

Comment: After looking at the problem further, I'm going to try to First check if an item exists in my responses list that matches the day of the week, and check the month, if those items aren't on the list, I'll add them in, if not, then I'll just update the values. This way I can just loop over the list and build it that way. 

I'll try to update with an answer if I am able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
var models = new List<DateHourResponseModel>(); //Should be a filled list, not empty like this
var modelMap = new Dictionary<(int, bool), AbsenceAnalysisResponse>();
foreach (DateHourResponseModel dateHour in models)
{
    Add(type: (int)dateHour.Date.DayOfWeek, isMonth: false);
    Add(type: dateHour.Date.Month, isMonth: true);


    void Add(int type, bool isMonth)
    {
        (int, bool) key = (type, isMonth);
        //Try to get existing responses
        if(!modelMap.TryGetValue(key, out AbsenceAnalysisResponse response))
        {
            //Create if first time adding to it
            modelMap[key] = response = new AbsenceAnalysisResponse
            {
                Type = type,
                IsMonth = isMonth,
                Count = 0,
                Hours = 0
            };
        }
        response.Count += 1;
        response.Hours += dateHour.Hours;
    }

}
//convert to list, can order if needed with .OrderBy()
List<AbsenceAnalysisResponse> analysisResponses = modelMap.Values.ToList();
```

The idea would be to loop through each model and add/modify to the list. Instead of searching through the list, a dictionary can be used with a unique key. In this case type + isMonth, in tuple form, but it could also be a string "{type}-{isMonth}" or something. If the key is not found then it will be created, otherwise just modified. At the end, turn the Dictionary into a list of its values. There are other ways of doing this, but this should be a good approach

Comment: This is awesome, thank you so much for your feedback! I need way more practice with manipulating lists etc. 

I was starting to try to figure out a way to do something like this. I'm going to try to implement something along these lines right now and I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: @CabsHere, if Gekctek's answer is helpful to you, please accept the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I literally just finished implementing the code, and it works wonderfully! Even better is that I learned a lot from that, and truly appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to post another solution I found while tinkering with this. I really liked Gekctek's answer, and used that initially. I think this one might be slightly more readable? Happy to receive any feedback.

```
private AbsenceAnalysis GetAbsenceAnalysisFromData(List<DateHourResponseModel> dateHourModel)
    {
        var analysis = new List<AbsenceAnalysisResponse>();

        foreach (var data in dateHourModel)
        {
            var week = analysis.FirstOrDefault(x =>
                x.Type == (int)data.Date.DayOfWeek && x.IsMonth == false);
            var month = analysis.FirstOrDefault(x =>
                x.Type == (int)data.Date.Month && x.IsMonth == true);
            if (week == null)
            {
                week = new AbsenceAnalysisResponse
                {
                    Count = 0,
                    Hours = 0,
                    IsMonth = false,
                    Type = (int)data.Date.DayOfWeek
                };
                analysis.Add(week);
            }

            if (month == null)
            {
                month = new AbsenceAnalysisResponse
                {
                    Count = 0,
                    Hours = 0,
                    IsMonth = true,
                    Type = data.Date.Month
                };
                analysis.Add(month);
            }

            week.Count += 1;
            week.Hours += data.Hours;
            month.Count += 1;
            month.Hours += data.Hours;
        }
```